# How to use " ind.sup" on a MCA analysis?

Tags: r, correspondence-analysis

I cant run my MCa with a `ind.sup`, I dont know why.
 Here's my code :

```
library(FactoMineR)
data_ACM <- data[80000:81000,] 

res.AMC <- MCA(data_ACM, ncp = 6, graph = F, ind.sup = 700)
Error in eigen(crossprod(t(X), t(X)), symmetric = TRUE) : 
infinite or missing values in 'x'
```

dpu(data[1:10,]) returns this :

```
"SOHDZET", "SOHDZF", "SOHDZFT", "SOKFXD", "SOKFXF", "SOM31BL4B1D", 
"SONFZD", "SONFZF", "SOVJZC", "SOVJZE", "SOVJZET", "SOVJZF", 
"SOVJZFT", "SOVJZJ", "SOZAAZ", "SP01", "SP21", "SP308", "SP41", 
"SP4DWC", "SP61", "SP81", "SR11", "SR1F0H", "SR1G0H", "SR1H06", 
"SR1J0H", "SR1J22", "SR1J32", "SR1L22", "SR1L32", "SR1M22", 
"SR270E", "SR31", "SR4DWC", "SR51", "SR81", "SR8J32", "SR8L32", 
"SREU0H", "SRH1ELC", "SRH1ELCD", "SS11", "SS31", "SS51", 
"SS55", "SS71", "SS91", "ST12", "ST72", "ST785E", "STA", 
"STADRX01AG", "STADRX01SG", "STAFNX01AG", "STAFNX01SG", "STAGZX01SG", 
"STAHLX01AG", "STAHLX01SG", "STAHUX01AG", "STAHUX01SG", "STAV", 
"STB", "STBV", "STC", "STCDCA", "STCV", "SU31", "SU35", "SU55", 
"SU55A", "SV10", "SV10EM", "SV1V12", "SV31", "SVA", "SVAV", 
"SW11", "SW31", "SW51", "SW52X400", "SW52X700", "SW53K2", 
"SW53K200", "SW53K9", "SW53K900", "SW5441", "SW5449", "SW58K2", 
"SW58K200", "SW58K3", "SW58K7", "SW58K9", "SW58K900", "SW5952", 
"SW5953", "SW5957", "SW5959", "SW59G200", "SW59G300", "SW59G700", 
"SW59G900", "SW6142", "SW6149", "SW61P2", "SW61P200", "SW61P9", 
"SW61P900", "SW61S200", "SW61S900", "SW6542", "SW6549", "SW65P2", 
"SW65P200", "SW65P9", "SW65P900", "SW65S200", "SW65S900", 
"SW6942", "SW71", "SW7140", "SW7141", "SW7144", "SW7146", 
"SW7362", "SW743200", "SW743900", "SW7462", "SW7469", "SW793200", 
"SW793700", "SW793900", "SW7962", "SW7964", "SW7967", "SW7969", 
"SW8042", "SW8142", "SX11", "SX31", "SX71", "SXBHW6", "SXBHY6", 
"SXHMP6", "SXHMZ6", "SXHNZ6", "SXHNZT", "SY11", "SY31", "SY33", 
"SY34", "SY53", "SY54", "SY71", "SYN1E", "SZ58K3", "SZ58K7", 
"SZ5953", "SZ5957", "SZ59G300", "SZ59G700", "SZ7144", "SZ7146", 
"SZ793700", "SZ7964", "SZ7967", "SZ799400", "T11", "T12", 
"T1X000", "T1X004", "T1X300", "T1X305", "T1X805", "T1XE05", 
"T1XF05", "T27WWT270", "T27WWT271", "T27ZRT270", "T27ZRT271", 
"T2DG1", "T2DH1", "T2DH2", "T2DJ1", "T2DJ2", "T2W300", "T2W305", 
"T2W800", "T2W805", "T2WE05", "T2WF05", "T31DD03", "T31EE01", 
"T32AA", "T32AA01", "T32AA02", "T32AA03", "T32AA04", "T32BB", 
"T32BB01", "T32BB02", "T32BB05", "T32BB06", "T32CC", "T32CC01", 
"T32CC02", "T32CC03", "T32CC04", "T32DD", "T32EE", "T3408", 
"T3419", "T3435", "T3448", "T3467", "T3DB1", "T3DE1", "T3DE2", 
"T3LA1", "T3LA2", "T3X000", "T3X100", "T3X300", "T3X305", 
"T3X800", "T3X805", "T3XE05", "T3XF05", "T4BBD", "T4BBG", 
"T4BCD", "T4BCE", "T4BCF", "T4DCA", "T4DCD", "T4DCT", "T4DCX", 
"T4DCY", "T4X000", "T4X100", "T4X305", "T4X405", "T4X800", 
"T4X805", "T4XE05", "T4XF05", "T4XG05", "T5408", "T5419", 
"T5435", "T5448", "T5808", "T5819", "T5835", "T5848", "T5X000", 
"T5X200", "T5X205", "T5X300", "T5X305", "T5X405", "T5X800", 
"T5X805", "T5XF05", "T5XG05", "T6EB1", "T6EB4", "T6EB6", 
"T6EB7", "T6ED5", "T6EE2", "T6MB1", "T6MB6", "T6MB7", "T6MC1", 
"T6MD5", "T72", "T7JA1", "T7W200", "T7W205", "T7W300", "T7W405", 
"T7WG05", "T824833", "T82W433", "T82W434", "T8344", "T8358A", 
"T8378A", "T8380", "T8390A", "T8394", "T83T4", "T844433", 
"T844434", "T844533", "T844544", "T845034", "T845043", "T845044", 
"T8458", "T847433", "T847443", "T847833", "T8478A", "T8480", 
"T8488", "T849033", "T849043", "T8490A", "T8494", "T8494B43", 
"T8494B44", "T84T4", "T84T443", "T84T444", "T84T543", "T84T544", 
"T84T833", "T84T843", "T855", "T857", "T85T4", "T85T8", "T9408", 
"T9419", "T9435", "T9448", "T9508", "T9519", "T9535", "T9548", 
"T9808", "T9819", "T9835", "T9848", "T9PG2", "TA", "TA12", 
"TA12F2", "TA12J5", "TA12L2", "TA12L5", "TA13008", "TA13035", 
"TA13068", "TA1308", "TA1335", "TA1368", "TA14", "TA16008", 
"TA16035", "TA16068", "TA1608", "TA1635", "TA1668", "TA2", 
"TA22", "TA23H", "TA23MB", "TA23MQG", "TA2422", "TA2422A", 
"TA28MB", "TA32408", "TA32419", "TA32468", "TA40", "TA40AKS", 
"TA40AMS", "TA43035", "TA43068", "TA4308", "TA4319", "TA4335", 
"TA4368", "TA4408", "TA4419", "TA4435", "TA4468", "TA60AMS", 
"TA60BLMB", "TA72L2", "TA72L5", "TA8408", "TA8419", "TA8435", 
"TA8468", "TA9408", "TA9419", "TA9435", "TA9468", "TA94E08", 
"TA94E19", "TA94E35", "TA94E68", "TAA408", "TAA419", "TAA435", 
"TAA468", "TAA8408", "TAA9408", "TAA94E08", "TAAA408", "TAAP11", 
"TAAW10", "TABCAS", "TABCDS", "TAC408", "TAC419", "TAC468", 
"TAD308", "TAD3G08", "TAF408", "TAF419", "TAF435", "TAF468", 
"TAJ3G008", "TAJ3G08", "TAK1367", "TAK4367", "TAKD467", "TAKU467", 
"TAKV467", "TAM3019", "TAM3035", "TAM3068", "TAM319", "TAM335", 
"TAM368", "TAM6019", "TAM6035", "TAM6068", "TAM619", "TAM635", 
"TAM668", "TAN308", "TAN419", "TAN435", "TAN468", "TAN619", 
"TAN635", "TAN668", "TANT30", "TAS335", "TAS3G08", "TATB", 
"TATF", "TATHA", "TATHB", "TATJA", "TATJB", "TAU8470", "TAUA470", 
"TAW4035", "TAW4068", "TAW6035", "TAW6068", "TAX100", "TAX300", 
"TAZ100", "TAZ300", "TB", "TB2", "TB2412", "TB367", "TBAABS", 
"TBABBS", "TBAP12", "TBAV10", "TBBCBS", "TBC1NPLY", "TBC1NRLY", 
"TBCAAS", "TBCADS", "TBCAES", "TBCBAS", "TBCBDS", "TBCBES", 
"TBDCAS", "TBDCDS", "TBDCES", "TBE1OVM", "TBE1OVN", "TBE2PZN", 
"TBE2UZN", "TBE4TWN", "TBE4TYN", "TBE4TYNC", "TBE5IWN", "TBE5IWNC", 
"TBE5TWM", "TBE5TWN", "TBE5TWNC", "TBE5TYN", "TBGMSLV", "TBGMTLVI", 
"TBGNSLV", "TBGNSLVC", "TBGNSLY", "TBGNTLVI", "TBIF5P11M51AZ1", 
"TBIF5P21M52CZ1", "TBNT30", "TBUR20", "TBX200", "TBX205", 
"TBX300", "TBX305", "TBX405", "TBXE05", "TBXG05", "TBZ200", 
"TBZ205", "TBZ300", "TBZ305", "TBZ405", "TBZ800", "TBZE05", 
"TBZG05", "TC2", "TCAP11", "TCAP12", "TCAV10", "TCTG05", 
"TCY405", "TCYG05", "TD2", "TD367", "TD4HSJ", "TD4HTH", "TDABKS", 
"TDABTS", "TDABUS", "TDAP11", "TDAV10", "TDAW10", "TDAW10M", 
"TDAW10U", "TDFBAS", "TDGCKS", "TDGCTS", "TDGCUS", "TDHCAS", 
"TDSY61", "TDUHZJ", "TDX8ZA", "TDXFVJ", "TE2", "TE51", "TEABKL", 
"TEABTL", "TEAP12", "TEBBAL", "TECCKL", "TECCTL", "TEDCAL", 
"TENT30", "TESY61", "TF08II51", "TF08J551", "TF08M351", "TF35II51", 
"TF35J551", "TF35M351", "TF408", "TF419", "TF435", "TF448", 
"TF48II51", "TF48J551", "TF48M351", "TFABAL", "TFABKL", "TFABSL", 
"TFABTL", "TFABUL", "TFAP12", "TFAY10", "TFBCAL", "TFBCKL", 
"TFBCSL", "TFBCTL", "TFBCUL", "TG08GCA1", "TG08GCS1", "TG08ICA1", 
"TG08ICS1", "TG08M351", "TG08M3A1", "TG2", "TG35GCA1", "TG35GCS1", 
"TG35ICA1", "TG35ICS1", "TG35M351", "TG35M3A1", "TG408", 
"TG419", "TG435", "TG448", "TG48GCA1", "TG48GCS1", "TG48ICA1", 
"TG48ICS1", "TG48M351", "TG48M3A1", "TGABAL", "TGABKL", "TGABSL", 
"TGABTE", "TGABTL", "TGBN", "TGCCAL", "TGCCKL", "TGCCSL", 
"TGCCTE", "TGCCTL", "TGFCAL", "TGFCTL", "TGFCUL", "TH308", 
"TH348", "TJAC9S", "TJAN91", "TJAN9S", "TJBBAL", "TJBBTE", 
"TJBBTL", "TJBBUL", "TJBCAL", "TJBCTE", "TJBCTL", "TJBCUL", 
"TK308", "TK348", "TKACAL", "TKACTE", "TKACTL", "TKACUL", 
"TLB310", "TLEF5D14A63ZZ1", "TLEF5D24M62ZZ1", "TLEF5D31M62ZZ1", 
"TLEF5D51M66ZZ1", "TLEF5D61D7", "TLEF5P31M64ZZ1", "TLEF5P41D71ZZ1", 
"TLEF5P44D71ZZ1", "TM4BUL", "TM4DBC", "TP260", "TPAD", "TPADJ", 
"TPAE", "TPAEJ", "TQF8D62M53AZ1", "TQF8D82A51AZ1", "TR160", 
"TR160T", "TR467", "TR567", "TR7969", "TR9145", "TR9245", 
"TS08ICS1", "TS08MCS1", "TS31", "TS48ICS1", "TS6142", "TS6149", 
"TS61E2", "TS61P2", "TS61P200", "TS61P9", "TS61P900", "TS61S200", 
"TS61S900", "TS65E2", "TS65P2", "TS65P200", "TS65P9", "TS65P900", 
"TS65S200", "TS65S900", "TS7202", "TS7206", "TS7432", "TS743200", 
"TS7439", "TS743900", "TS7462", "TS7469", "TS7932", "TS793200", 
"TS793900", "TS7962", "TS7969", "TS90C5", "TS90K5", "TS9145", 
"TS91J500", "TS91K5", "TS91K500", "TS9245", "TS92K5", "TS92K500", 
"TS94K2", "TS94K5", "TS97C2", "TS97C5", "TT132", "TT408", 
"TT419", "TT435", "TT448", "TT508", "TT519", "TT535", "TT548", 
"TT808", "TT819", "TT835", "TT848", "TTFN44", "TU308", "TU319", 
"TU348", "TU408", "TU419", "TU435", "TU448", "TU467", "TU508", 
"TU519", "TU535", "TU548", "TU567", "TU808", "TU819", "TU835", 
"TU848", "TVUF", "TVUR20", "TVUR20U", "TW308", "TW319", "TW348", 
"TW3T08", "TW3T19", "TW3T35", "TW3T48", "TWUR20", "TX31", 
"TX71", "TY260", "TY260T", "U11", "U11T", "U2", "U2MAC", 
"U2NAC", "U6UA", "U6UB", "U6UC", "U6UE", "U6UF", "U6UG", 
"U6UJ", "U6UJT", "U6UK", "U6UR", "U6UR9", "U6UT", "U6UT9", 
"U6UU", "U6UU9", "U6UW", "U6UWT", "U857", "U858", "U859533", 
"U85T", "U9C1G6", "U9C1GH", "U9C1K6", "U9C1KH", "U9C2G6", 
"U9C2K6", "U9CYG6", "U9CYK6", "U9VCK5", "UA5FV81P", "UA5FWC", 
"UA5FWC1", "UA5FXH1P", "UA6FYC", "UA71", "UA9HR8", "UA9HR82PS", 
"UA9HR8P", "UA9HR8PS", "UA9HZC", "UA9HZC1", "UA9HZH1P", "UA9HZHP", 
"UARFJHP", "UARHB8P", "UARHE8", "UARHHA", "UARHJH1P", "UARHJHP", 
"UARHRJ", "UB11", "UB31", "UB51", "UB53", "UB71", "UB91", 
"UC11", "UC31", "UC71", "UC91", "UD11", "UD1Y11", "UD51", 
"UD5FS0", "UD5FV81P", "UD5FWC", "UD5FXH1P", "UD5FXHP", "UD6FYC", 
"UD71", "UD91", "UD9HR8", "UD9HR82PS", "UD9HR8P", "UD9HR8PS", 
"UD9HZC", "UD9HZC1", "UD9HZC1CU1", "UD9HZH1P", "UD9HZH1PCU1", 
"UD9HZHP", "UDC1G6", "UDC1K6", "UDC2G6", "UDC2K6", "UDC3G6", 
"UDC3K6", "UDCAG5", "UDCAK5", "UDCCG5", "UDCCK5", "UDCEG5", 
"UDCEK5", "UDCGG5", "UDCGK5", "UDCJG5", "UDCJK5", "UDCMG5", 
"UDCMK5", "UDCNG5", "UDCNK5", "UDCSG6", "UDCSK6", "UDCUG5", 
"UDCUG6", "UDCUK5", "UDCUK6", "UDCVG5", "UDCVK5", "UDCYG6", 
"UDCYK6", "UDRFJHP", "UDRHB8P", "UDRHE8", "UDRHHA", "UDRHJH1P", 
"UDRHJHP", "UDRHRJ", "UE11", "UE31", "UE51", "UE9HR8", "UE9HR8P", 
"UE9HZC1", "UE9HZH1P", "UF11", "UF1Y32", "UF31", "UF51", 
"UF8U52", "UF8UL2", "UF91", "UG31", "UG51", "UH11", "UH31", 
"UH51", "UK11", "UK31", "UK51", "UL91", "UM11", "UM51", "UM71", 
"UM91", "UMC7D2", "UN10", "UN13", "UN1A22", "UN71", "UN8B42", 
"UN8D32", "UN8F42", "UN91", "UP11", "UR11", "UR31", "UR51", 
"UR91", "URMD21", "US31", "US91", "USD135", "USD145", "USD1F5", 
"USD1K5", "USD1W5", "USDBL5", "USDUK5", "USDUW5", "UT31", 
"UT71", "UU11", "UU51", "UU6M", "UU71", "UU91", "UV51", "UV71", 
"UV91", "UW71", "UW91", "UX11", "UX31", "UX51", "UX71", "UX91", 
"UXC1", "UY11", "UY31", "UY51", "UY71", "UY91", "UZ10BC", 
"UZ68BC", "UZA2BC", "UZA8BC", "UZBABD", "UZJ100LGNAEKW", 
"V1DKS", "V1DVS", "V1JKS", "V1JVS", "V23CGRHE", "V23WGNXE", 
"V23WGNXES", "V24WGNXF", "V24WGNXFS", "V24WNDF", "V24WNDFS", 
"V24WNHF", "V24WNHFS", "V25WGNX", "V25WGRX", "V26WGNX", "V26WGNXS", 
"V2DAC", "V2JAC", "V2W200", "V2W300", "V36MM01", "V36NN01", 
"V36PP01", "V36RR01", "V36SS01", "V36TT01", "V37CC03", "V37DD03", 
"V37EE01", "V37FF01", "V37GG01", "V3X208", "V3X308", "V3XG08", 
"V43WGRXE", "V44WGNXF", "V44WGNXFS", "V44WNHF", "V45WGRX", 
"V46WGNX", "V46WGRX", "V46WNH", "V46WNHS", "V4X208", "V4X300", 
"V4X308", "V4X408", "V4XE08", "V4XG08", "V4Y208", "V4Y408", 
"V4YG08", "V521L22HCR167", "V521SLLDA5865", "V521SLLDAR165", 
"V5W208", "V5W408", "V5WG08", "V6419", "V6435", "V64WMN", 
"V7419", "V7435", "V9X300", "VA", "VA51", "VA71", "VA91", 
"VABHSH", "VABHVB", "VABHXH", "VAJ", "VAJI", "VAJIA", "VAL", 
"VAM", "VAN", "VANA", "VB11", "VB31", "VB71", "VB84035", 
"VB84035M", "VB84069", "VB84069M", "VB8435", "VB8469", "VB86035", 
"VB86035M", "VB86069", "VB86069M", "VB8635", "VB8669", "VB94035", 
"VB94069", "VB9435", "VB9469", "VB96035", "VB96069", "VB9635", 
"VB9669", "VBBHSH", "VBBHVB", "VBBHXH", "VBW4035", "VBW4069", 
"VBW435", "VBW469", "VBW6035", "VBW6069", "VBW635", "VBW669", 
"VBY4035", "VBY4069", "VBY6035", "VBY6069", "VBZ4035", "VBZ4069", 
"VBZ6035", "VBZ6069", "VBZ6E035", "VBZ6E069", "VC11", "VC31", 
"VC419", "VC435", "VC51", "VC619", "VC635", "VC91", "VCA419", 
"VCA435", "VCA619", "VCA635", "VCDZ", "VCM36V", "VD0419", 
"VD0619", "VD11", "VD21SDDAAN735", "VD21SEEAAN735", "VD31", 
"VD419", "VD435", "VD51", "VD619", "VD635", "VD71", "VD91", 
"VDGCS", "VDGDS", "VDL", "VDM", "VDNS", "VDPA", "VDPAF", 

"XWYWMX", "XWYWTP", "XWYWTX", "XWYWXT", "XWZLUR", "XX11", 
"XX31", "XX51", "XY11", "XY31", "XY51", "Y3AA", "Y3AB", "Y3AC", 
"Y3ACA", "Y3AE", "Y3AF", "Y3AG", "Y3AH", "Y3AHA", "Y3AL", 
"Y3AP", "Y3AR", "Y3AS", "Y3AT", "Y3AW", "Y3AX", "Y3AY", "Y3AZ", 
"Y3CN", "Y4CW", "Y4CZ", "Y4GB", "Y4GG", "Y4GM", "Y4GN", "Y4GR", 
"Y4GU", "Y4GV", "Y4GW", "Y4GX", "Y4GY", "Y4GZ", "Y4MZ", "Y4NW", 
"Y4NX", "Y4NY", "Y4NZ", "Y4RM", "Y4RN", "Y4TD", "Y4TN", "Y4TR", 
"Y4TS", "Y4TT", "Y4TU", "Y4TV", "Y4TX", "Y4WC", "Y4WG", "Y4WH", 
"Y4WK", "Y51AA01", "Y51BB0", "Y51BB01", "Y51CC01", "Y51DD01", 
"Y51FF0", "Y51HEE0", "Y51HEE01", "Y910", "YA01", "YA1MFA", 
"YA1MFB", "YA1MRA", "YA2MFA", "YA2MFB", "YA2MRA", "YA3MFA", 
"YA3MFB", "YA3MRA", "YA41", "YA61", "YA81", "YA9S", "YAAMFA", 
"YAAMFAAX", "YAAMFB", "YAAMFBBX", "YAAMPA", "YAAMRA", "YABMFA", 
"YABMFAAX", "YABMFB", "YABMFBBX", "YABMPA", "YABMRA", "YASMFA", 
"YASMFB", "YASMPA", "YASMRA", "YATMFA", "YATMFB", "YATMPA", 
"YATMRA", "YAUMPA", "YAUMRA", "YB01", "YB1MFA", "YB1MFB", 
"YB1MFC", "YB1MRB", "YB2MFA", "YB2MFB", "YB2MFC", "YB2MRB", 
"YB2R", "YB3MFA", "YB3MFB", "YB3MFC", "YB3MRB", "YB4R", "YB61", 
"YB81", "YBAMAA", "YBAMAAAX", "YBAMAB", "YBAMABAX", "YBAMAC", 
"YBAMACAX", "YBAMADAX", "YBAMCB", "YBAMCBAX", "YBAMCC", "YBAMCCAX", 
"YBAMDBAX", "YBAMDCAX", "YBAMFA", "YBAMFAAX", "YBAMFB", "YBAMFBAX", 
"YBAMFBBX", "YBAMFC", "YBAMFCBX", "YBAMFCCX", "YBAMGBAX", 
"YBAMHBAX", "YBAMHCAX", "YBAMRB", "YBB5D11M6", "YBB5P11M6", 
"YBB5P21M5", "YBB5P31M5", "YBB5P51A4", "YBBMAA", "YBBMAB", 
"YBBMABAX", "YBBMAC", "YBBMACAX", "YBBMADAX", "YBBMCB", "YBBMCBAX", 
"YBBMCC", "YBBMCCAX", "YBBMDBAX", "YBBMDC", "YBBMDCAX", "YBBMFA", 
"YBBMFAAX", "YBBMFB", "YBBMFBAX", "YBBMFBBX", "YBBMFC", "YBBMFCBX", 
"YBBMFCCX", "YBBMGBAX", "YBBMHBAX", "YBBMHCAX", "YBBMPB", 
"YBBMRB", "YBC5D31M6", "YBCP11M6", "YBCP41M6", "YBDMAB", 
"YBDMAC", "YBDMADAX", "YBDMDC", "YBDMDCAX", "YBDMFA", "YBDMFB", 
"YBDMFBAX", "YBDMFBBX", "YBDMFC", "YBDMFCBX", "YBDMFCCX", 
"YBDMHCAX", "YBDMPB", "YBPMFB", "YBPMFC", "YBPMPB", "YBSMFA", 
"YBSMFB", "YBSMFC", "YBSMRB", "YBTMFA", "YBTMFB", "YBTMFC", 
"YBTMPB", "YBTMRB", "YBUMFA", "YBUMFB", "YBUMFC", "YBUMPB", 
"YBUMRB", "YC1MFA", "YC1MFB", "YC1MFC", "YC21", "YC2MFA", 
"YC2MFB", "YC2MFC", "YC3MFB", "YC3MFC", "YC41", "YC81", "YCAMAB", 
"YCAMABAX", "YCAMAC", "YCAMACAX", "YCAMACAXL", "YCAMAD", 
"YCAMADAX", "YCAMCB", "YCAMCBAX", "YCAMCC", "YCAMCCAX", "YCAMCCAXL", 
"YCAMDB", "YCAMDBAX", "YCAMDC", "YCAMDCAX", "YCAMFB", "YCAMFBAX", 
"YCAMFBBX", "YCAMFC", "YCAMFCBX", "YCAMFCCX", "YCAMGCAX", 
"YCAMHC", "YCAMHCAX", "YCBMAB", "YCBMABAX", "YCBMAC", "YCBMACAX", 
"YCBMACAXL", "YCBMAD", "YCBMADAX", "YCBMCB", "YCBMCBAX", 
"YCBMCC", "YCBMCCAX", "YCBMCCAXL", "YCBMDB", "YCBMDBAX", 
"YCBMDC", "YCBMDCAX", "YCBMFB", "YCBMFBAX", "YCBMFBBX", "YCBMFC", 
"YCBMFCBX", "YCBMFCCX", "YCBMGC", "YCBMGCAX", "YCBMHC", "YCBMHCAX", 
"YCDMAB", "YCDMABAX", "YCDMAC", "YCDMACAX", "YCDMACAXL", 
"YCDMAD", "YCDMADAX", "YCDMCB", "YCDMCC", "YCDMCCAX", "YCDMCCAXL", 
"YCDMDB", "YCDMDC", "YCDMDCAX", "YCDMFB", "YCDMFBAX", "YCDMFBBX", 
"YCDMFC", "YCDMFCBX", "YCDMFCCX", "YCPMFB", "YCPMFC", "YCSMFB", 
"YCSMFC", "YCTMFA", "YCTMFB", "YCTMFC", "YCUMFB", "YCUMFC", 
"YD2MFC", "YD3MFC", "YDBMACAX", "YDBMACAXL", "YDBMBCAX", 
"YDBMCCAXL", "YDBMDCAXL", "YDBMFCBX", "YDBMFCCX", "YDBMFCCXL", 
"YDBMGCAXL", "YDBMHCAXL", "YDDMACAX", "YDDMACAXL", "YDDMCCAXL", 
"YDDMDCAXL", "YDDMFCBX", "YDDMFCBXL", "YDDMFCCX", "YDDMFCCXL", 
"YDDMHCAXL", "YDPMFC", "YDTMFC", "YDUMFC", "YE01", "YE41", 
"YE81", "YF61", "YF81", "YG01", "YG41", "YM", "YM11", "YM31", 
"YM91", "YN", "YN1P", "YN2B", "YN2BCF", "YN2BDG", "YN2C", 
"YN2M", "YN2MC", "YN2MD", "YN4M", "YN5B", "YN5M", "YN9P", 
"YN9S", "YNA", "YNSF5DH1M6", "YNSF5P71M5", "YNSF5P91M6", 
"YP", "YP11", "YP31", "YP51", "YP91", "YPA", "YS", "YS31", 
"YS3B55D", "YS3F55E", "YS3F55L", "YS3F59E", "YS3GG4JA6A01", 
"YS3GG4LA6F01", "YS3GG4LM6F02", "YS3GG4ZA6A01", "YS3GG4ZA6F01", 
"YS3GG4ZM6A01", "YS3GG4ZM6F01", "YS51", "YS91", "YT11", "YT54Y", 
"YT71", "YT91", "YU11", "YU31", "YU51", "YU71", "YV1PW10BD", 
"YV1PW68BC", "YV1PW79B0", "YV1PW79B1", "YV1PWA2BC", "YV1PWA8B1", 
"YV1PWA8BC", "YV1PWA8BD", "YV1PWARBC", "YV1PZ68BC", "YV1PZA2BC", 
"YV1PZA8B4", "YV1PZA8BC", "YV71", "YV91", "YY23P", "YYCAD2M", 
"Z10", "Z12", "Z12AA01", "Z12AA02", "Z12BB01", "Z16AMJ", 
"Z16AMN", "Z34AA01", "Z34AA02", "Z34AA03", "Z34AA04", "Z34AA05", 
"Z34BB01", "Z34BB02", "Z34BB03", "Z51AA01", "Z51BB01", "Z51CC01", 
"ZA31", "ZAAMFA/BX", "ZAAMFAAX", "ZAAMFABX", "ZAAMFBAX", 
"ZAAMNABX", "ZAAMPA", "ZAAMRA", "ZADA", "ZADAB", "ZADAC", 
"ZADB", "ZADBB", "ZADBC", "ZADD", "ZADDB", "ZADE", "ZADEB", 
"ZADFT", "ZADH", "ZADJ", "ZADM", "ZADN", "ZAKE", "ZAKET", 
"ZAKF", "ZAKH", "ZAKJ", "ZALAT", "ZALB", "ZALC", "ZALF", 
"ZALG", "ZALH", "ZALHT", "ZALJ", "ZAPAPA", "ZAPMFAAX", "ZAPMFAAY", 
"ZAPMNAAX", "ZAPMPA", "ZARMFAAX", "ZARMFABX", "ZARMFBAX", 
"ZARMNAAX", "ZARMPA", "ZARMRA", "ZATMFAAX", "ZATMFABX", "ZATMFBAX", 
"ZATMNAAX", "ZAXZ", "ZAZA", "ZAZAT", "ZAZB", "ZAZBT", "ZAZC", 
"ZAZD", "ZAZE", "ZAZF", "ZAZH", "ZAZJ", "ZAZK", "ZAZL", "ZAZT", 
"ZAZTT", "ZAZU", "ZAZY", "ZAZZ", "ZB31", "ZB51", "ZB71", 
"ZB8S", "ZB8Y", "ZB8Z", "ZBAMAAAX", "ZBAMABAX", "ZBAMDAAX", 
"ZBAMDBAX", "ZBAMDCAX", "ZBAMFAAX", "ZBAMFABX", "ZBAMFBAX", 
"ZBAMNAAX", "ZBAMNBAX", "ZBAMRB", "ZBC", "ZBD", "ZBPANBAX", 
"ZBPANCAX", "ZBPARB", "ZBPMABAY", "ZBPMACAY", "ZBPMBBAY", 
"ZBPMBCAY", "ZBPMCBAX", "ZBPMDCAY", "ZBPMFAAY", "ZBPMFABY", 
"ZBPMFBAY", "ZBPMGBAY", "ZBPMGCAY", "ZBPMHCAY", "ZBPMNAAX", 
"ZBPMNABY", "ZBPMNBAY", "ZBPMNCAX", "ZBPMNCAY", "ZBPMRB", 
"ZBPWFAAY", "ZBPWFABY", "ZBPWNBAY", "ZBRMAAAX", "ZBRMABAX", 
"ZBRMACAX", "ZBRMCBAX", "ZBRMDAAX", "ZBRMDBAX", "ZBRMDCAX", 
"ZBRMFAAX", "ZBRMFABX", "ZBRMFBAX", "ZBRMGBAX", "ZBRMGCAX", 
"ZBRMHCAX", "ZBRMNAAX", "ZBRMNBAX", "ZBRMNCAX", "ZBRMRB", 
"ZBTMFAAX", "ZBTMFABX", "ZBTMFBAX", "ZBTMNAAX", "ZBTMNBAX", 
"ZBTMNCAX", "ZBZMACAY", "ZBZMDCAY", "ZBZMFAAY", "ZBZMFABY", 
"ZBZMFBAY", "ZBZMGCAY", "ZBZMHCAY", "ZBZMNBAY", "ZBZMNCAY", 
"ZC31", "ZC51", "ZCBHZH", "ZCBHZW", "ZCPANBAX", "ZCPANBBX", 
"ZCPANCAX", "ZCPANCBX", "ZCPMABAY", "ZCPMACAY", "ZCPMAGAY", 
"ZCPMBBAY", "ZCPMBCAY", "ZCPMCBAY", "ZCPMCCAY", "ZCPMDBAY", 
"ZCPMDCAY", "ZCPMFAAY", "ZCPMFABY", "ZCPMGCAY", "ZCPMHCAX", 
"ZCPMHCAY", "ZCPMNBAY", "ZCPMNBBY", "ZCPMNCAY", "ZCPMNCBY", 
"ZCPWABAY", "ZCPWACAY", "ZCPWCBAY", "ZCPWCCAY", "ZCPWDBAY", 
"ZCPWDCAY", "ZCPWNBAY", "ZCPWNCAY", "ZCRMABAX", "ZCRMACAX", 
"ZCRMAGAX", "ZCRMCBAX", "ZCRMCCAX", "ZCRMDBAX", "ZCRMDCAX", 
"ZCRMFAAX", "ZCRMFABX", "ZCRMGCAX", "ZCRMHCAX", "ZCRMNBAX", 
"ZCRMNBBX", "ZCRMNCAX", "ZCRMNCBX", "ZCTMCBAX", "ZCTMCCAX", 
"ZCTMNBAX", "ZCTMNBBX", "ZCTMNCAX", "ZCTMNCBX", "ZCZMABAY", 
"ZCZMACAY", "ZCZMAGAY", "ZCZMCBAY", "ZCZMCCAY", "ZCZMDBAY", 
"ZCZMDCAY", "ZCZMDGAY", "ZCZMFAAY", "ZCZMFABY", "ZCZMGCAY", 
"ZCZMGGAY", "ZCZMHCAY", "ZCZMHGAY", "ZCZMNBAY", "ZCZMNBBY", 
"ZCZMNCAY", "ZCZMNCBY", "ZD11", "ZD31", "ZD51", "ZD71", "ZE2", 
"ZE31", "ZF111", "ZF31", "ZFANF6EK6", "ZFANF6EKA", "ZG31", 
"ZH51", "ZH71", "ZHNC9L", "ZHNE9L", "ZM31", "ZN31", "ZN57", 
"ZN67", "ZN8M", "ZP31", "ZR31", "ZR71", "ZRHNYH", "ZRHNYW", 
"ZT14", "ZT24", "ZT35", "ZT37", "ZT38", "ZT45", "ZT47", "ZT48", 
"ZT55", "ZT57", "ZT58", "ZT65", "ZT67", "ZT68", "ZV18", "ZV30", 
"ZV38", "ZV41", "ZV81", "ZW41", "ZW61", "ZW81", "ZZT220LAEMNKW", 
"ZZT220LALMNKW", "ZZT221LAEMEKW", "ZZT221LAEPEKW", "ZZT221LALMEKW", 
"ZZT221LALPEKW", "ZZT230LBLFGHW", "ZZT231LBLFVFW", "ZZT251LALMEKW", 
"ZZT251LALMNKW", "ZZT251LALPEKW", "ZZW30LAKMQHW"), class = "factor")), .Names 
= c("Lib_Marque__MRQ_", 
"Lib_Modele__MOD_", "Lib_Carrosserie__CAR_", "Lib_Energie__ENE_", 
"Puiss_Fiscale", "Nb_Places", "Nb_Cylindres", "Cylindree", "Vitesse_Max", 
"Puiss_Reelle_kW", "Puiss_Reelle_DIN", "Regime_Puiss", "Couple_Max", 
"Regime_Couple_Max", "Nb_Rapports", "Longueur", "Largeur", "Hauteur", 
"Empattement", "Voie_AV", "Voie_AR", "Poids_Vide", "PTAC", "Charge_Utile", 
"Valeur_Neuf_Orig_EUR", "Code_SRA"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = 
"data.frame")
```

Thank you for your kind help

Comment: Could you `dput(data)` and post the result in the question, or post some fake data that makes the same error?

Comment: "YBB5P21M5", "YBB5P31M5", "YBB5P51A4", "YBBMAA", "YBBMAB", 
    "YBBMABAX", "YBBMAC", "YBBMACAX", "YBBMADAX", "YBBMCB", "YBBMCBAX", 
    "YBBMCC", "YBBMCCAX", "YBBMDBAX", "YBBMDC", "YBBMDCAX", "YBBMFA", 
    "YBBMFAAX", "YBBMFB", "YBBMFBAX", "YBBMFBBX", "YBBMFC", "YBBMFCBX", 
    "YBBMFCCX", "YBBMGBAX", "YBBMHBAX", "YBBMHCAX", "YBBMPB", 
    "YBBMRB", "YBC5D31M6", "YBCP11M6", "YBCP41M6", "YBDMAB",

Comment: "Lib_Modele__MOD_", "Lib_Carrosserie__CAR_", "Lib_Energie__ENE_", 
"Puiss_Fiscale", "Nb_Places", "Nb_Cylindres", "Cylindree", "Vitesse_Max", 
"Puiss_Reelle_kW", "Puiss_Reelle_DIN", "Regime_Puiss", "Couple_Max", 
"Regime_Couple_Max", "Nb_Rapports", "Longueur", "Largeur", "Hauteur", 
"Empattement", "Voie_AV", "Voie_AR", "Poids_Vide", "PTAC", "Charge_Utile", 
"Valeur_Neuf_Orig_EUR", "Code_SRA"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
>

Comment: dput(data) returns me something way too long to e put in a comment. here's a part of it. thank you for your help nihil

Comment: Yes, if it's possible, you can edit the question, adding the `dput(data)` result in the question, not in the comments.

Comment: Done, It was still to long I had to delete a part of it.

Comment: I know what you mean, but in this way it is not usable in R by a user that would help, so it is quite useless: using `dput(data)` and post the full result, make everybody to have your data, and try your code: without data it is very difficult to run your code, reproduce your error, and detect a solution. Also, your problem is with an option that use furthermore individuals (rows), and you are giving only 10 rows, when the option uses the 700th. However, does your script works without the `ind.sup` option?

Comment: @nihil Yes my script works fine without it.

Comment: Furthermore, I tried with a fake data and I still have the same error.

Comment: It's hard without data, the only thing that I can suppose is that maybe you can have some NA, on the 700th row.